# SignalR: Sending data using GlobalHost.ConnectionManager can't see method

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm new to `SignalR` so I might be missing something elementary.

When using:

```
public class EventDispatcher : Hub
{
    void Send(string sStrategyID, string sMessage)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventDispatcher>();
        context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(sStrategyID, sMessage);
    }
}
```

The client identifies `eventDispatcher` but not `broadcastMessage`.

```
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.eventDispatcher;
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (sStrategyID, sMessage) {
            console.log("Id: " + sStrategyID + " ,Event: " + sMessage);
        };
    });
```

[watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcDat.png)

Comment: Are you starting the connection? If so, can you include a larger code snippet?

Comment: And why are you using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<EventDispatcher>` inside your hub?

Comment: @Monso, by starting connection do you mean '$.connection.hub.start().done(function ()...' ?

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo, because when i use 'Clients.All.broadcastMessage(sStrategyID, sMessage);' i get this error 'Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported.'

Comment: So, you're trying to call client method outside the Hub?